# GUIText is behind GUITexture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First off I have looked around and I can see many posts about this and they all point towards the Z position of the text, however I have changed this to minus and positive and my text is always drawn behind my GUITexture.

So this is what I have setup

My GUI has 4 text boxes

```
Score
Lives
Level
Time
```

Now I have an object called GameManager which uses this code below to draw my two GUI sprites

```
void OnGUI()
    {
        float screenHeight = Screen.height / 12f * 1.5f;
        GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width * 2, screenHeight), textureBand);
        GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, Screen.height - screenHeight, Screen.width * 2, screenHeight), textureBand);
    }
```

However what ever I do my text is always drawn below my GUITexture so I can never see my text, could I get a little help with this one.

Comment: By the way, I would avoid using the old `GUI` class and the old Unity UI system at all costs, if possible. The new UI system is pretty great, I would consider migrating to it, if you don't have to support a lot of legacy code.

Comment: When you say the "new" UI system. I have only just started to learn Unity. I have created a new UI object which displays my 4 text objects, however all the UI can do is an Image or Raw. Are you referring to these?

Comment: No, it's a completely new system, unrelated to `GUI` class. I think you'll find this useful: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui

Comment: Will take a look later when I get home, but it seems like it should be the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're drawing into the same location, you need to specify the depth of each draw to make sure they're sorted correctly. Take a look at the unity docs here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html

Set a higher depth value for the textures you want drawn further back (behind the text) like so:

```
GUI.depth = 1;
```

Comment: I have just tried

void OnGUI()
 {
  float screenHeight = Screen.height / 12f * 1.5f;
  GUI.depth = 1;
  GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, 0, Screen.width * 2, screenHeight), textureBand);
  GUI.DrawTexture (new Rect (0, Screen.height - screenHeight, Screen.width * 2, screenHeight), textureBand);
 }

But still doesn't seem to write the text above my textures

Comment: Make sure you're setting the depth back to 0 after you draw. Once depth is set, it will be set for all GUI draw calls. You only want that set for these specific textures. Alternatively, specify the depth on the text elements as well.

Comment: Just tried this and the sprites are still drawn above my text

Comment: So strange. Do you have the same issue if you draw the GUIText in OnGUI along with the textures?

Comment: Its ok I followed Max Yankov comment on using the new GUI and not the old one and it seems to work fine, but thank you for your answer and time